# Write to a file in Ruby with every iteration of a loop

Tags: ruby

I am dealing with two large files that will not fit in my RAM:

- I wish to load two lines of each, process them and write them.
- I need it to be two lines at a time due to the nature of these files.

My program is not writing lines as it runs, and it quickly uses my RAM and is killed, with the target file created but still empty.

I tried `$stdout.puts`, `f.puts`,  `|f| f.write` and flushing.

This does produce the desired output in small files, but separating my files just does not seem like the way to go.

I have 2 files both the same number of lines and both following the format:

> >Line1
>   Line2

And I need to output them as

> @Line 1 from file 1
>   Line 2 from file 1
>   + Line 1 from file 2
>   Line 2 from file 2

Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

file1 = File.open(ARGV[0])
file2 = File.open(ARGV[1])
outFile = File.open(ARGV[2], 'a')
i = 1
(file1.each_slice(2)).zip((file2.each_slice(2))).each do |f1l, f2l|
  outFile.write (f1l[0].tr(">", "@")+"\n")
  outFile.write (f1l[1]+"\n")
  outFile.write (f2l[0].tr(">", "+") +"\n")
  outFile.write (f2l[1]+"\n")
  if (i % 100) == 0
    GC.start
  end
  i = i+1
end
file1.close
file2.close
outFile.close
```

Comment: Maybe `$stdout.flush` after each call to `puts`? https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-flush

Comment: Thanks @jmm but it seems this only flushes to my OS, which also has a buffer and keeps it there. >:(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately you're missing useful information. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. What is the minimal input that demonstrates the problem, and what is your expected output given that input? Currently you're asking us to imagine the input and output which is not the SO way.

Comment: When writing Ruby, we don't use CameCase for variables. ItsAReadabilityThing. Also, don't skimp on whitespace, especially around operators. Whitespace doesn't affect running speed, but it sure helps you, and others, read your code. "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Code for readability." — John Woods

Comment: Instead of separate `open` and `close` statements, use nested `File.open` with blocks for the first two files. It's more idiomatic Ruby and Ruby will automatically close the files when they're finished reading.

Comment: Sorry @theTinMan, I agree is hard to read, should I edit it to reproduce the problem with the minimal input now that has been solved? just so it might help people in the future ? I agree is hard to read and has some unnecessary info and lacking some

Comment: Yes, actually you should. Remember that SO isn't only about solving your problem, but about solving the problem of those who are following along and later need a solution to the same problem. You have inside knowledge of the problem that can help them fit it to what they're working on. SO isn't about the immediate fix, it's also about the education and long term fixes for many, many, others. And, thank you very much for asking. You'll do well here! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-write) to create two input files.

```
FNameIn1 = 'in1'
File.write(FNameIn1, "cow\npig\ngoat\nhen\n")
  #=> 17
```

We can use [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-read) to confirm what was written.

```
puts File.read(FNameIn1)
cow
pig
goat
hen
```

```
FNameIn2 = 'in2'
File.write(FNameIn2, "12\n34\n56\n78\n")
  #=> 12 
puts File.read(FNameIn2)
12
34
56
78
```

Next, use [File::open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html#method-c-open) to open the two input files for reading, obtaining a file handle for each.

```
f1 = File.open(FNameIn1)
  #=> #<File:in1> 
f2 = File.open(FNameIn2)
  #=> #<File:in2>
```

Now open a file for writing.

```
FNameOut = 'out'
f = File.open(FNameOut, "w")
  #=> #<File:out>
```

Assuming the two input files have the same number of lines, in a `while` loop read the next line from each, combine the two lines in some ways and the write the resulting line to the output file.

```
until f1.eof
  line11 = f1.gets.chomp
  line12 = f1.gets.chomp
  line21 = f2.gets.chomp
  line22 = f2.gets.chomp
  f.puts "%s %s, %s %s" % [line11, line21, line12, line22]
end
```

See [IO#eof](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-eof), [IO#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) and [IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-puts).

Lastly, use [IO#close](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-close) to close the files.

```
f1.close
f2.close
f.close
```

Let's see that `FileOut` looks like.

```
puts File.read(FNameOut)
cow 12, pig 34
goat 56, hen 78
```

We can have Ruby close the files by using a block for each `File::open`:

```
File.open(FNameIn1) do |f1|
  File.open(FNameIn2) do |f2|
    File.open(FNameOut, "w") do |f|
      until f1.eof
        line11 = f1.gets.chomp
        line12 = f1.gets.chomp
        line21 = f2.gets.chomp
        line22 = f2.gets.chomp
        f.puts "%s %s, %s %s" % [line11, line21, line12, line22]
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

```
puts File.read FNameOut
cow 12, pig 34
goat 56, hen 78
```

This is in fact how it's normally done in Ruby, in part to avoid the possibility of forgetting to close files.

Here's another way, using [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach), which, without a block, returns an enumerator, allowing the use of [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), as referenced in the question.

```
e1 = File.foreach(FNameIn1).each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: File:foreach("in1")>:each_slice(2)>
e2 = File.foreach(FNameIn2).each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: File:foreach("in2")>:each_slice(2)> 

File.open(FNameOut, "w") do |f|
  loop do
    line11, line12 = e1.next.map(&:chomp)
    line21, line22 = e2.next.map(&:chomp)
    f.puts "%s %s, %s %s" % [line11, line21, line12, line22]
  end
end
```

```
puts File.read(FNameOut)
cow 12, pig 34
goat 56, hen 78
```

We may observe the values generated by the enumerator

```
e1 = File.foreach(FNameIn1).each_slice(2)
```

by repeatedly executing [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
e1.next
  #=> ["cow\n", "pig\n"] 
e1.next
  #=> ["goat\n", "hen\n"] 
e1.next
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

The `StopIteration` exception, when raised, is handled by [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking out of the loop (which is one reason why `loop` is so useful).

Comment: This is great, the problem is, I need to process 2 lines at a time, this files come in pairs of lines. So i need to load 2 lines at a time. hence my attempt of each_slice(2).

Comment: I added a method that uses `each_slice`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I am glad you even took the time to add a method with each_slice. Best reagards.

Comment: Works like a charm and looks much more simple, again, thanks a lot for taking time of your day to help out the newbies.

Comment: A question for readers: `IO::foreach`, when used with a block, closes the file (being read) when exiting the block. When used without a block, as I have, an enumerator is returned. In that case the docs do not indicate if and when the file is closed. I presume it is closed when the method in which `foreach` was executed is exited. Correct? (No handle is available to close the file manually, of course.)

Comment: I suspect it's closed when Ruby exits. File handles are more global in nature, they're allocated to the process, not to the method. But, yes, Ruby should _eventually_ deallocate/garbage-collect local variables inside the method, but I still lean toward Ruby holding off until the end in this sort of case. Maybe one of the really smart guys will educate us. :-)